# How to scroll a web page in Coded UI Test with VS 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I'm recording Coded UI Tests with VS 2012, which shall test the functions of a web application.

After I loaded the web page, I click on a button to start p.e. a job application.

After the next page has loaded on the same site, my problem begins.
The entry controls are at the end of the web site.
To take a look and input data into the entry controls, I must scroll down.
The recording produced the following method in the UIMap.

Designer.cs:

```
public void Scrollen()
{
    #region Variable Declarations
    Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.AllThreads;
    this.UIGoogleMozillaFirefoxWindow.UIItemPropertyPage.UIBewerbungDemoFirmaDocument.WaitForControlExist();
    this.UIGoogleMozillaFirefoxWindow.UIItemPropertyPage.UIBewerbungDemoFirmaDocument.WaitForControlReady();
    Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.UIThreadOnly;
    WinControl uIBewerbungDemoFirmaDocument = this.UIGoogleMozillaFirefoxWindow.UIItemPropertyPage.UIBewerbungDemoFirmaDocument;
    #endregion

    // Click "Job application" document
    Point pt = new Point(1390, 553);
    int count = 0;
    while (!uIBewerbungDemoFirmaDocument.TryGetClickablePoint(out pt) && count < 20)
    {
        count++;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);

        if (count == 20)
            Console.WriteLine("ClickablePoint not found");
    }

    Mouse.Click(uIBewerbungDemoFirmaDocument, new Point(1390, 553));
    Mouse.MoveScrollWheel(10);
}
```

As You can see, I tried WaitForControlExist, WaitForControlReady, TryGetClickablePoint and the method MoveScrollWheel.
But neither Mouse.Click nor Mouse.MoveScrollWheel are working.

And in the next method, where I click into the first of the entry fields, I get a message at execution time, that the click event produces an error, because the control is hidden (because it's down below on the website, out of visible range).
After several tests this is making me crazy.

Any idea what has gone wrong and how can I scroll down the web site, so my entry controls are in visible range?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Control.EnsureClickable(). Or you can use below mentioned function to scroll the page until the control is not clickable.

```
public static void ScrollAndClick(HtmlControl Control)
    {
        bool isClickable = false;
        if (Control.TryFind())
        {
            while (!isClickable)
            {
                try
                {
                    Control.EnsureClickable();
                    Mouse.Click(Control);
                    isClickable = true;
                }
                catch (FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException)
                {
                    Mouse.MoveScrollWheel(-1);
                    throw;
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new AssertInconclusiveException("Control Not Found");
        }

    }
```

You can also add condition related to timeout to make sure it don't go to infinite loop.

Let me know if you are having issue with this at your end.

Comment: Hello Kuldeep,

Thanks for Your answer, but it doesn't really help.
When i call the method with p.e. the HtmlButton to which i want to navigate, i get an UITestControlNotVisibleException at Control.EnsureClickable().

Comment: is the control loaded properly. because such type of exception generally occurs due to page load issue.

Comment: Before the EnsureClickable method i execute WaitForControlExist and WaitForControlReady.
Normally the control should exist and be ready for input actions, isn't it?

Comment: Yes,That's true have checked in debug mode. before EnsureClickable control object is getting binded with various value or it is showing Null. WaitforcontrolExit adn WaitforControlReady may have timeout before getting actual control.

Comment: I have found another way to do and record that.
After the page was loaded, i click on the scrollbar and use the up- or down-cursor button.